# Google Double Click GADDoubleClickParameters.h file not found ios

Tags: ios, double-click

I want to implement Google Double Click into my iPad. 
I am following

```
https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/ios/doubleclick/
```

In setup section doc specify to copy GADDoubleClickParameters.h file.

I have searched a lot but could not get this file in SDK . 
Sdk that i get is

```
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadios
```

Can somebody guide me how can i implement double click in ios if i follow above guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mismatch between Google AdSense Mobile and Google AdMob Ads; GADDoubleClickParameters.h is required by the formed, while you are downloading the latter.

It seems that Google AdMob Ads supersedes AdSense Mobile:

> The new SDK provides numerous advantages over the previous AdMob and AdSense for Mobile Applications SDKs and lays the framework as we work towards a single, comprehensive app monetization solution. Key features include access to the latest ad units, tablet formats for Android, iOS 4.3, and Windows Phone 7 support. ([source](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/))

If you want to use Google AdMob Ads, I would suggest having a look at the sample projects that Google provides.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So for implementing Google Double Click in ios i need to use Google AdSense or Google AdMob?

Comment: I think Google is converging its different frameworks, but I don't know about Double Click, so I am not sure about your question...